# Will adding an event of same kind append or override the previously added event with the same name?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I append an event at start:

```
myObject.on("myEvent",myFuncONE);
```

later on the same object should get the same event but with another function

```
myObject.on("myEvent",myFuncTWO);
```

will that override the first one or will both functions be executed?

Comment: It will keep on adding. It won't override

Comment: What is `myObject`? What happens to your event handlers is determined by `on`. The standard is not to override, though, like `addEventListener` does it.

Answer (score 1):

They will both be executed. You can have as many event handlers as you want, and they'll all be run.